# UIWebView shouldStartLoadWithRequest not calling for some links

Tags: ios, twitter, uiwebview

In my `UIWebView` I’m loading twitter page. I want to open all the clicks inside the `webView` as a separate page. So I implemented the `shouldStartLoadWithRequest`:

```
-(BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request     navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType

{
    //if inlineLink.
    if (UIWebViewNavigationTypeLinkClicked == navigationType )
    {
        InLineWebViewController *viewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:kInLineWebViewControllerStoryboardID];
        viewController.urlString= [[request URL] absoluteString];
        [self presentViewController:viewController animated:YES completion:nil];
        return NO;
    }

    return YES;
}
```

This code is working perfectly for some links. But unfortunately its not working for all the links, for example the twitter reply/re-tweet links. Any help would be appreciable. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

As per my knowledge the function `shouldStartLoadWithRequest` gets called only for urls which is going to load content or, load new webview frame. See [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIWebViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIWebViewDelegate/webView%3ashouldStartLoadWithRequest%3anavigationType%3a)

There are few kind of urls which might be assigned to javascript that doesn't actually load a page, may not work..